# Как упаковать Dbf таблицу с помощью Delphi 10.3 Rio

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

Не могу удалить данные из таблицы, они отмечены как удаленные но требуют упаковку. Как сделать это программно? Пишет что file is in use при упаковке что делать?

```
  `procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  var god,data,max,date:string;
  begin
  date:=formatdatetime('dd.mm.yyyy',(DateTimePicker1.Date));
  god:=copy(formatdatetime('yyyy',(DateTimePicker1.Date)),1,4);
  data:=formatdatetime('ddmm',(DateTimePicker1.Date));
  ADOQuery1.Close;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Append('Select max(date_pogr) as max from g_rabn.dbf where god='+''''+'''');
  ADOQuery1.Open;
  max:=ADOQuery1.FieldByName('max').asstring;
  if date<>max then
  begin
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:='delete from g_rabn.dbf where god='+''''+'''';
  ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:='pack g_rabn.dbf';
  ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
  showmessage('Неправильная отчетная дата');
  end
  else
  begin
  ADOQuery1.SQL.text:='update g_rabn.dbf set god='+''''+god+'''' +' where god='+''''+'''';
  ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.text:='update g_rabn.dbf set data='+''''+data+'''' +' where data='+''''+'''';
  ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;

 end;

 end;
 end.`
```

Comment: А разве не 'PACK TABLE g_rabn.dbf'?

Comment: Пишет file is in use

Answer (score 0):

Файл должен быть открыт монопольно

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста более развернутый ответ. Зачем и как открывать монопольно?